# Action of an operator-valued function of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

I am currently dealing with an operator-valued function
$f(\hat{T})$ of the following kind:
$$f(\hat{T}) =\sqrt{1 + b\hat{T}^2} $$
where $b$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\hat{T}$ is a linear operator acting on the usual Hilbert space of quantum mechanics, i.e. $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
What I am interested in is to define its action on a generic physical state $|\Psi\rangle$ in the representation of its own eigenbasis (of course I am supposing that this exists).

If I am correct, I could proceed with a series expansion of the previous operator.
This leads me to write:
$$\sqrt{1 + b\hat{T}^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (b\hat{T}^2)^n $$
where $c_n$ is the proper generalized binomial coefficent and the series should converge for $\left\|b\hat{T}^2\right\|\leq 1$.

This should not be a problem in principle, nevertheless, it turns out that, in my framework, the operator $\hat{T}$ is the usual momentum operator of quantum mechanics $\hat{p}$, which - to my knowledge - is unbounded with respect its domain of definition (which should be a dense subset of the Hilbert space  $L^2(\mathbb{R})$).
From this, I deduce that the previous procedure is not suitable for the present case.
Hence what can be done? My question can be exposed from two different points of view:

1)How can I find the action of this operator if the series expansion fails to be a proper instrument?

2)Is it possible to "impose" that the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ be bounded - like some kind of constraint, which I imagine could lead to a redefinition of the operator itself? From a mathematical and physical point of view is this even possible?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are after, but, normally, for [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula), as for infinite-dimensional operators, one uses some version of Sylvester's formula, and one investigates convergence properties afterwards.

If, by "its own eigenbasis", you mean the eigenbasis of momentum,
$$
|\Psi\rangle= \int\!\!dp~~|p\rangle \langle p| \Psi\rangle,
$$ then you evidently   have
$$\sqrt{I+b\hat p^2}|\Psi\rangle= 
\int\!\!dp~~|p\rangle ~\sqrt{1+b  p^2} ~\langle p| \Psi\rangle,$$
as you appear to anticipate. (In sadistic undergraduate QM, in momentum space, this [presents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Spinless_position%E2%80%93space_wave_function) as $f(p)\Psi(p)$.)

You may be familiar with the operator based on the Casimir operator  of angular momentum,
$$
\sqrt{\hat L^2+1/4} -1/2 ,
$$
whose eigenvalues are $\ell$ when acting on irreducible spin multiplets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you have written is clear for me and it allows me to clarify my final goal. I am sorry if I was somehow 'obscure' in the question.
First of all, I would like to ask you one thing: in what you have written is implicit that $f(\hat{p})|\Psi\rangle=f(p) |\Psi\rangle$; this does sound obvious and intuitive and maybe it is but how can you demonstrate this? For sure I am missing something elementary here.

Comment: Secondly, and this is the point where I am clarifying myself, I was insisting on the 'series expansion' road because I would like to relate the mean value of the square root operator with the mean value of $\hat{p}$. This is something that apparently you cannot do with Sylvester's formula, since the mean value of course depends on the function $\Psi(p)$.

Comment: On first comment. ? NO! *p* is strictly an eigenvalue of $\hat p$ for its eigenstate $|p\rangle$. So *p* is always a dummy variable  present *inside* a p-integral. In momentum-space wavefucntions, of course it is *f(p)*, by the definition of Dirac bra-ket mechanics!

Comment: On second comment. By mean value you mean expectation value? That always depends on the state. Unless you have a spectrum/ distribution of eigenvalues given. Define your terms.

Comment: I am sorry, in the first comment that was a typo (because of copy/paste). Of course what I meant was $f(\hat{p})|p\rangle=f(p)|p\rangle$.

On the second comment: yes, with 'mean value' I mean 'expectation value'.

Comment: Yes, of course, a function of a diagonal operator is the diagonal operator with entries being functions of the respective eigenvalues! If you thought about it, it *is* the heart of Sylvester's formula.